# Give different number of Rows for multiple cells in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[image]

Hello,
i have created a `UITableView` in which it has two different cells `DynamicFormCell` and `StaticFormCell`, so the `DynamicFormCell` can be displayed number of times i have a data from a server telling me how many forms i need for the `DynamicFormCell` and the `StaticFormCell` is always the same and doesn't change so i am having difficulty giving different number of rows for each cell.i tried giving the two cell a `tag` of `0` and `1` respectively and used this code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if(tableView.tag == 0){
            return 5//return five dynamic cells
        }
        if(tableView.tag == 1){
            return 1//return one static cell
        }
    }
```

but this doesn't work and i also tried removing all the `tags` and `if statements` in the above code and just doing this `return 5` this just gave me one `DynamicFormCell` and five `StaticFormCells`.

i also gave different classes for the two cells so i can assign them separately:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if(indexPath.row == 0){
            //firstRow make dynamic
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DynamicFormsCell") as! DynamicFormsCell
            return cell
        }else{
            //static form data
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "StaticFormsCell") as! StaticFormsCell
            return cell
        }
    }
```

so my question is, is it possible to do this using table views and how can i do it? if not what other options do i have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to have multiple types of cell in single tableview. It has nothing to do with function

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
```

You should return there cells as,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
 return (count of dynamic cells + count of static cells)
}
```

I assume, you only have to display static cells in the bottom. So if there are total 5 cells then 4 cells are dynamic and 5th cell would be static.

So code for, `cellForRowAt indexPath:` will be,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if(indexPath.row < (count for dynamic cells)){
            //first 4 Rows make dynamic
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DynamicFormsCell") as! DynamicFormsCell
            return cell
        }else{
            //last row static form data
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "StaticFormsCell") as! StaticFormsCell
            return cell
        }
    }
```

Comment: @jhon, Glad that it helped.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing right now is checking if the TableView's tag is 0 or 1. Which is not you want to do, since you're using only one TableView.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return (amount of DynamicCellsYouWant + amount of StaticCellsYouWant)
}
```

The second part of your code only works when you want the first cell to be a `DynamicFormsCell` and the rest to be a `StaticFormsCell`.

Comment: i am not using two table views i have two cells in one table view

Comment: My bad, I'll change my answer